# Getting UserId and ShardId after Evernote authentication in C#

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, evernote, evernote-app-notebook

I'm developing a Windows client for some integration with Evernote desktop.
In particular, I need to build locale (in-app) links to notes, which requires the userId and shardId (evernote:///view/[userId]/[shardId]/[noteGuid]/[noteGuid]/).
Problem is, I don't find how to programmatically get userId and shardId.
I need to use ENSessionAdvanced instead of ENSession, and I will authenticate to Evernote by an API key, as follows:

```
ENSessionAdvanced.SetSharedSessionConsumerKey("key", "secret");
if (!ENSessionAdvanced.SharedSession.IsAuthenticated)
    ENSessionAdvanced.SharedSession.AuthenticateToEvernote();
```

From there, I could get notebooks and notes, and everything, but no idea of where to get userId and shardId.
Help!

Comment: I believe you're working with [this sdk](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-windows/blob/master/samples/CS/SampleApp/SampleApp/Form1.cs)  is that correct?  Does `ENSessionAdvanced.SharedSession.AuthenticateToEvernote();` return anything?

Comment: Precisely nothing.

Comment: This link https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/note_links.php says "The shardId can be obtained by calling the getUser method on the userStore object" but no idea of how to get the "userStore" object... I can get the ENSessionAdvanced.SharedSession.PrimaryNoteStore but it's different from UserStore.

Comment: https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/UserStore.html  - looks like it might take you further, but are you sure `ENSessionAdvanced.SharedSession.AuthenticateToEvernote();` doesn't return an object `AuthenticationResult`?  Try something like `var result = ENSessionAdvanced.SharedSession.AuthenticateToEvernote();` and see what result gives you to work with.

Comment: No trace of UserStore, using ENSessionAdvanced, @JimmySmith. And no AuthenticationResult. But... maybe I've got a track...

Comment: EN.EDAM.Type.Notebook seems to have a "Contact" property, which is... the user. No trace of doc, on Evernote, but it seems it. Contact.Id and Contact.ShardId. So...`EN.EDAM.Type.Note note = this.store.GetNote(noteGuid, false, false, false, false);
            EN.EDAM.Type.Notebook notebook = this.store.GetNotebook(note.NotebookGuid);
            return "evernote:///view/" + notebook.Contact.Id + "/" + notebook.Contact.ShardId + "/" + noteGuid + "/" + noteGuid + "/";`

Comment: Seems the solution and it compiles but still not tested. Problems with connection now but that's another problem... I'll post the solution as soon as I have it working. Thanks, @JimmySmith!

Comment: I'm glad to help.  Make sure you post as I feel this one needs more documentation.

Comment: Indeed, @JimmySmith. But I'm stuck with authentication, now, and Evernote support totally absent... [Auth problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60185006/problem-authenticating-to-evernote-with-net-sdk)

Comment: I wonder what in the chain IS keeping the session properties as that's all we need to crack into. I'd think it would be something easily accessible from `ENSessionAdvanced.SharedSession`